# Processing Tools Help Documentation for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, documentation

I'm used to ArcGIS but am attracted to QGIS for its open source (free) nature.  At present I'm trying to use native QGIS processing tools and also script my own algorithms (was used to geoprocessing with ArcPy).

The main hurdle I find with QGIS is the lack of documentation on how to use the existing tools (something similar to ArcGIS Help website).  ArcGIS Help is excellent.  Usually a simple read through their description and examples for any given tool has me able to use it very quickly.  I realize Esri has the budget for this and QGIS is open source, free, and programmed by volunteers, but without good explanations on how to use QGIS tools how can one expect to master them as much as the ArcGIS tools?

Example:  ArcGIS Help's entry for their [Add Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000047000000) tool

Is there a book, a website, etc. where similarly helpful instruction is given on the tools available in QGIS and how to use them?

I am familiar with using "processing.alghelp(..tool name..)" in QGIS' python console, but the "help" results offer no real instruction on how to use the tools.

Comment: To distinguish this question from the one that has been made a duplicate of will, I think, need you to [edit] it so that it focuses on a particular piece of online help that you are looking for i.e. not something as broad as the QGIS Processing framework as a whole.

Comment: There is a Q&A here that describes how to help document QGIS Processing tools: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121058/how-to-add-documentation-for-qgis-processing-algorithms

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I've since read other "duplicate" questions but none address my concern.  However I agree it was a broad question so I have illustrated with an example in a new thread entitled 'QGIS Tool Scripting Help with "Select by attribute"'.  Thanks again.